# Is it possible to get accelerometer data from watch app when app is in background?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have requirement for which I need to monitor accelerometer data from the apple watch and based on certain combination of data received from accelerometer, need to trigger event to iOS app. Is it possible for watch app to fetch data in background without user interacting with it?

Answer (score 1):

Remember the watch app v1.0 is just display for the iPhone app. All the logic is currently done on the phone and watch app just display that information. Given that, iPhone have the Motion Chip (M7) that collects movement data all the time and stores. When you launch an app, it can request that movement data history. Therefore the app doesn't have to be running all the time. This saves on battery life.

Comment: I need to get motion data from the watch app to detect specific kind of hand movement, for the purpose of analyzing behaviour of patient with specific conditions. So can't use iphone motion data. Not sure if 3rd party apps can do this.

Comment: IWatch 2.0 will allow native apps on the watch. You will need To check the SDK itself.